# Derivability of graph properties in first-order logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Consider a signature containing only a two—place predicate equality symbol and a two-place predicate symbol R, interpretations are sets with binary relations (oriented graphs). Is it possible to express the following
graph properties/relations with first-order formulas: acyclicity; connectivity?

I would like to use formulas of countable power to prove both facts like:
$\land\exists x_1, ... , x_n \forall x \forall y (R(x,x_1)\land R(x_1, x_2)\land ... \land R(x_n,y))$ for connectivity and similar for acyclicity but is that correct?

I realized that this is an incorrect formula and now I don't know what to do

Comment: the first conjunction is taken by n

Comment: You want to turn the initial conjunction into a disjunction, otherwise you're requiring that there's a path from $x$ to $y$ of every length. On the other hand, first order logic does not allow variable-arity conjunctions and disjunctions like this. What tools do you have for showing there is or isn't a first order formula for something?

Comment: @TomKern The compactness theorem

Answer (score 1):

Acyclicity is not expressible with just one formula, but is expressible with countably infinitely many formulas. More precisely, for all $n$, “There is no cycle of length $n$“ is clearly expressible as a first-order sentence.

Conversely, a standard compactness theorem argument will show that connectivity is not a first-order property. For suppose we have a set $S$ of first-order sentences equivalent to connectivity. Add constant terms $a, b$ and, for each $i$, the axiom $\phi_i$ = “There is no path of length $i$ from $a$ to $b$”, and apply compactness in the obvious way to get a contradiction.

Comment: Actually, this is not true, it is not clear how to define an infinite conjunction in first-order logic on an infinite universe. Let's assume that there really isn't a cycle of length n, but then we'll never know about it in our formula. As for point a, in point b, let's take a graph from one point, it is connected and satisfies our axioms

Comment: @Quark There is no need to do an infinite conjunction. A property $P$ is expressible in first-order logic if there is some set $S$ such that for all $M$, $M \models S$ if and only if $P(M)$. No individual formula in $S$ can use infinite conjunction, but $S$ can be infinite. As for your one-point graph, there is a path of length $0$ from $a$ to $b$ when $a = b$.